# Laravel Config ODBC Driver

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-4, odbc

I need to config Laravel 4 to use the ODBC PDO Driver for SQL Server 2000

I have tested it in a plain PHP file and it works perfectly, However, I can't get the right config inside Laravel.

This is my connection string >

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyHOST;Database=myDb;User Id=sa;Password=;");
```

I got this so far in the Laravel config/database.php

Edit

Ok, i followed the instructions  from https://github.com/ccovey/odbc-driver and i configured:

I changed it to

```
'odbc' => array(
        'driver' => 'odbc',
        'dsn' => 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyServer',
        'grammar' => 'SqlServerGrammar',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'database' => 'staPPM',
    ),
```

Im getting an error FatalErrorException, Grammar not Found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel 4 still does not support ODBC directly, you'll have to do it yourself or you can try to use this driver: https://github.com/ccovey/odbc-driver.

You'll have to add connection that should look something like:

```
'odbc' => array(
   'driver' => 'odbc',
   'dsn' => 'Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};System=my_system_name;',
   'grammar' => 'DB2',
   'username' => 'foo',
   'password' => 'bar',
   'database' => '',
   'grammar' => 'SqlServerGrammar',
),
```

As noted in the package docs, you have to provide a **valid DSN** to connect to your server: those ones are examples of valid connection strings:

```
"Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=AdventureWorks;"

"Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=ORACLE8i7;Persist Security Info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\bin\Northwind.mdb"

"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=c:\bin\book1.xls"

"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=c:\bin"
```

To know if your DSN is valid, you better test the DNS outside Laravel.

If you have access to a Linux, you can test it by doing:

```
apt-get install unixodbc

isql -v DSN_NAME db_username db_password
```

And it should answer with:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

There's a bug in ccovey's source code and, for now, you should alter the source of `ODBCDriverConnection` to:

```
/**
 * Default grammar for specified Schema
 * @return Schema\Grammars\Grammar
 */
protected function getDefaultSchemaGrammar()
{
    return $this->withTablePrefix(new \Illuminate\Database\Schema\SqlServerGrammar);
}
```

I'll open an issue in the package Github so they get this fixed.

Comment: Im getting ERROR SQLSTATE[IM002] Data Source Name Not Found and no default driver specified

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/ccovey/odbc-driver? How did you installed it?

Comment: I followed every instruction, added the require to composer.json and i ran composer update, the console said Installing ccovey/odbc-driver-l4 and then i configured as I said above and i got that error

Comment: I think the problem now is that I dont know the exact config for the config/database.php

Comment: I added 'dsn' => 'Driver={SQL Server}',  now im getting Error: Neither DSN nor Server keyword supplied

Comment: You must provide information about your server, where it is supposed to connect? Locally, remotelly? Just edited to provide some more info.

Comment: OK,, Different error, FatalErrorException, Grammar Not Found... So the conection was succeful, but the grammar is not working

Comment: Ahh, SQLServerGrammar is NOT provided with the ccovey package... how can I supply it??????????????

Comment: Laravel provides it, you can just use Laravel's, check my edit.

Comment: Odd, just saw yours and looks like you have set the SqlServerGrammar in the right place. So it should be using Laravel's one.

Comment: Maybe its looking only in the ccovey package... should I just added? ... the ccovey instructions said to replace the DatabaseServiceProvider,, maybe its that

Comment: There, yes, the instructions say to add the grammar to the package, im  gonna try it

Comment: In the process of helping you I installed it here and my postgre drivers still worked, so ccovey's is forwarding to Laravel when it cannot find one.

Comment: Odd, I cannot find "Grammar not Found" in Laravel nor CCovey's source code. Looks like this exception is not from Laravel but your ODBC driver...

Comment: o.O It says: exactly. error: {"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException", "message":"Class 'Ccovey\\ODBCDriver\\Schema\\Grammars\\Grammar' not found, "file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\laravel\\vendor\\ccovey\\odbc-driver-14\\src\\Ccovey\\ODBCDrvier\\ODBCDriverConnection.php", "line":36

Comment: Ok, its definitely a problem with the Ccovey, i changed grammar to DB2 and it still cannot find the "Grammar" Class.....

Comment: It's a bug on CCovey's, there is no such file in the source of package.

Comment: I think its trying to locate the Grammar from the Ccovey package, but its not there

Comment: Change that line to `new \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars`, I think it was trying to reference Laravel's default Grammar.

Comment: \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar is an abstract class, cannot instantiate

Comment: Oh! :) So you can test `new \Illuminate\Database\Schema\SqlServerGrammar`, the one you need

Comment: Yess,, ahah that's exactly what I just did :D

Comment: Edit your answer adding that last part so I can mark it as correct