# Change grammar in eloquent configuration information

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, odbc

I added this configuration in eloquent, but the grammar attribute didn't take effect. I want to connect to MariaDB through odbc. But this database supports mysql syntax, not sql server syntax

Please help me, thank you all

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => 'your_server_name',
    'database' => 'your_database_name',
    'username' => 'your_username',
    'password' => 'your_password',
    'port' => 1433,
    'prefix' => '',
    'options' => [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    ],
    'grammar' => [
        'query' => Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar::class,
        'schema' => Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar::class,
    ],
],
```

Comment: [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660729/laravel-config-odbc-driver)?